# In beamerclass: How to set Style for specific pages?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I just require three types of pages. For all of those pages I want to declare a specific style, like the following:

- Mainpage: The Mainpage is only used once, at the beginning and includes author, title, date, institution and maybe something optional like a link of supported company or something like that..think about a small picture. I need to implement some boxes with rounded corners filled with a specific color. There shall be no headline or footline. Since I don't know much about beamer (just starting to work with beamer) I try to realise alot with tikz (like the rounded corner-boxes).
- Emptypage: The Emptypage will be used for the ToC or as a introductionpage to the next topic or for questions. I do not need a headline or footline.
- Content: The Content will need a headline and footline.

Next I have to implement some boxes for "definition, theorem, lemma, corollary, proposition". So if the user will type

```
\begin{definition}[thing, that will be defined]
    Definition of that thing.
\end{definition}
```

the output shall be a box with rounded corners with a heading "Definition: thing, that will be defined" with a specific background and below there has to filled in the definition. Some spacing left and right. (I guess, that this is easy)

Now I hope you know, what I need to do. My first question is:
How to declare mainpage, emptypage, contentpage?

Edit:
If I declare:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [rectangle, left color=gradient, right color=gradient!30!white, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=1cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

it only appears on the first page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{test}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Mainpage}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Emptypage}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Content}
        some content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

beamerthemetest.sty

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tikz}

% Declare the mainpage
    % only will be used for the mainpage

% Declare emptypage
    % only for the emptypage

% Declare contentpage
    % only for content
\definecolor{gradient}{HTML}{0E1778}

% headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [rectangle, left color=gradient, right color=gradient!30!white, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=1cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Comment: Your question boils down to the usage of `tcolorbox` I think. Please post a MWE so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for your response. First I only need to know how to declare different pagestyles. If I declare \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [rectangle, left color=gradient, right color=gradient!30!white, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=1cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
it only appears on the first page.

Comment: There is a frame option called `plain` that should remove head- and footlines. You could add that for specific frames.

Comment: Please do not post code fragments as comments but rather edit your post.

Comment: I did it like you mentioned.

Comment: Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @TeXnician tcolorbox will solve my definition-problem. Thanks. :) The MWE will be edited.

Comment: I've added a mwe. It's actually really plain.

Comment: Since I realised, that my work is closely redefining the madrid or warsaw package (just setting different colors and a specific footer) I will concentrate on modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generally it's better to only ask one question per question**

> Mainpage: The Mainpage is only used once, at the beginning and includes author, title, date, institution and maybe something optional like a link of supported company or something like that..think about a small picture. I need to implement some boxes with rounded corners filled with a specific color. There shall be no headline or footline. Since I don't know much about beamer (just starting to work with beamer) I try to realise alot with tikz (like the rounded corner-boxes).

You can simply use `\titlepage`. If you don't like the default layout or if you want to include additional information, you can redefine it using `\setbeamertemplate{titlepage}{...}`.

All the elements are already in boxes, you just have to make them visible by defining their colour, for example `\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=blue!60!black, fg=white}`. To make these boxes rounded, use `\useinnertheme{rounded}`.

To remove the head- and footline use the `plain` option for the frame.

> Emptypage: The Emptypage will be used for the ToC or as a introductionpage to the next topic or for questions. I do not need a headline or footline.

`plain` option, see above

> Content: The Content will need a headline and footline.

You already have the headline in your code, just define a footline in a similar way or use one of the default footlines from beamer

> Next I have to implement some boxes for "definition, theorem, lemma, corollary, proposition". So if the user will type

Beamer already has this, you just have to make them visible, for example:

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=green!70!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=green!40!black}
```

> not asked but...

You don't need `xcolor` or `graphicx` with beamer, as these are already provided.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tikz}

% Declare the mainpage
    % only will be used for the mainpage

% Declare emptypage
    % only for the emptypage

% Declare contentpage
    % only for content
\definecolor{gradient}{HTML}{0E1778}

% headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [rectangle, left color=gradient, right color=gradient!30!white, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=1cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=blue!60!black, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=green!70!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=green!40!black}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    \section{test}
    \begin{frame}{Content}
        some content
        \begin{definition}
            bal bla
        \end{definition}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]